# How do I make a Vertical Pillbar collapsible?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a site using Bootstrap 4 and have a side pill bar with some menu options for an admin page. On the pillbar I have one nav item that I want to be able to click on and have it expand out and give me a few more options on the pillbar.

This is what I have right now for the display of the page:

[image]

The three items below manual data entry are the items I want make collapsible and expand when I click on Manual Data Entry.

I have tried adding the collapse class to the li for the Manual Data Entry nav item, but when I do that it disappears. I'm guessing this is because it needs something to expand it.

Here is what I have so far code wise:

```
  <div class="col-lg-2">
            <ul id="adminPills"class="nav flex-column nav-pills bg-dark">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active text-muted" data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard"><span class="fas fa-chart-line"></span>   Dashboard</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-muted" data-toggle="tab" href="#permissions"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>    Permissions</a></li>                
                <li class="nav-item collapse"><a class="nav-link text-muted " data-toggle="tab" href="#permissions"><i class="fas fa-database"></i>    Manual Data Entry</a>
                    <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills bg-dark">
                        <div style="padding-left:0px;">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-muted" href="#">Historical Data</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-muted" href="#">Company News</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-muted" href="#">Financial Report</a></li>
                        </div>  
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-muted" data-toggle="tab" href="#email"><i class="fas fa-mail-bulk"></i>    Send Email to Users</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

How would I edit this code to make this possible?

Comment: If you want `Manual Data Entry` to toggle the collapsible, it should have `data-toggle="collapse"`, not `data-toggle="tab"`. And the `href` should point to the collapsible, not to a tab.

Comment: When you say the href should point to the collapsible what do you mean?

Comment: I meant `href="#yourCollapseElement"`. Have you read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)? *"...can show and hide multiple elements by referencing them with a JQuery selector in its `href` or `data-target`."*

Comment: I see, I was using the data-target instead to reference it, it is working now thank you!'

Comment: It would work with `data-target` as well. The problem was it activated both and the  `tab` was closing.